# Table Layout - Bootstrap Progress Bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tablelayout

I am trying to get the following effect:

[image]

Essentially what I have done is make a div with

```
display: table;
```

and then populated it with divs containing Font Awesome icons with

```
display: table-cell;
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abehnaz/wCHbc/1/

My problem right now is that I can't figure out how to get the line to go from the center of one table-cell to the center of the other table cell. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**

Here is how I got what I was looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/abehnaz/wCHbc/8/. This is a pretty wordy solution, but it does the job. The only thing left for me is to try to figure out how I could get a gap in between the top line and the bottom line. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/wCHbc/5/

Basically I created a new div that is the line and restored the structure as a simple div layout:

```
.line{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    top:25px;
    left:0px;
    height:10px;
    background:#00f;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

If you don't want the symbols with a transparent background, just add a background color:

```
.icon-star, .icon-rss{
    background:#fff;
}
```

Comment: This looks like it is on the right path. The thing is, why does it push the second icon out of the "slider" box? Is it possible to just have it in the background somehow? I would like it to auto-size as the slider re-adjusts.

Comment: Updated the post above with a new solution that works as you want. Just don't use the display:table; when you can always use a table tag, but in this case is better if you use a div structure layout ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with `position: absolute`

DEMO [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/wCHbc/3/)

```
.line {
    position: fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:7px;
    top:95px;
    left: 0;
    right:60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: blue;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

**EDITED**

I would use a progress bar for this

DEMO **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/wCHbc/4/)**

Comment: This is also looking like it is on the right track. The major issue I see here is that the bar is a fixed length. The "slider" element is dynamic, and can change widths. Is it possible to have the line do the same thing?

Comment: You can make it variable width. I would use a progress bar personally, see my edited *jsfiddle*

Comment: Progress bar idea is interesting. Not quite what I was looking for though. See my jsFiddle for the solution I got.

Comment: your fiddle looks good. it will not work in many browsers though due to the css3.